# django template doesn't display fields of a list of objects

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm currently working on a project using django 4.0.3 and I want to create a dashboard with the recent activities performed by a user. for exemple I have a LTA model and I want that whenever the user works on an LTA (create, read, or update) it is added to the recently viewed LTA. To do this I use a session key called "recently_viewed_lta" and whenever a user works on an lta it's Id is added to the session variable. This works fine, the problème is when I try to display them on a template it doesn(t display. I hope the code will help to understand my problem.

this is my view

```
def home(request):
ltas = Lta.objects.in_bulk(request.session["recently_viewed_lta"], field_name='numlta')
# ltas = Lta.objects.all()
env = Enveloppevol.objects.all()
rapports = Rapportvente.objects.all()
context = {
    'ltas': ltas,
    'env': env,
    'rapports': rapports
}
print(ltas)

return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

This is my home.html

```
<p class="fs-3">Activité récente</p>
<p>Here are the ltas {{ ltas }} </p>
<p>Here is the session {{ request.session.recently_viewed_lta }} </p>
    {% for i in request.session.recently_viewed_lta %}
    <p>Session element {{ i }}</p>

    {% for lta in ltas.items %}
    <p>Lta n° {{ lta.numlta }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
<hr>
```

this is the output in the browser

```
Here are the ltas {75684: <Lta: Lta n° 75684>, 232323: <Lta: Lta n° 232323>, 252525: <Lta: Lta n° 252525>, 424242: <Lta: Lta n° 424242>, 565656: <Lta: Lta n° 565656>}
Here is the session ['424242', '232323', '75684', '565656', '252525']
Session's elements
Lta n°
Lta n°
Lta n°
Lta n°
Lta n°
```

Though if I replace

```
ltas = Lta.objects.in_bulk(request.session["recently_viewed_lta"], field_name='numlta')
```

by

```
ltas = Lta.objects.all()
```

there is no problem and the template isplays correctly all the objects. What could the problem be ? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Because `in_bulk` returns a **dictionary**:

> **in_bulk()**
>
> in_bulk(id_list=None, *, field_name='pk')¶
>
> Takes a list of field values (id_list) and the field_name for those values, and returns a **dictionary** mapping each value to an instance of the object with the given field value.

If you send a dictionary on context, you can unpack key and value like this:

```
{% for key, lta in ltas.items %}
    <p>Lta n° {{ lta.numlta }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually the in_bulk was the very problem, but I used filter instead. But this is useful, it can help later. Thanks again

Comment: This was not the answer for your posted question?

Comment: I figured out the problem was with the type of list in_bulk actually returned (just what you're saying) so I used filter instead (that returns a list I knew how to manipulate) because I didn't know how to unpack key and value

Comment: By the way, is there a way in django to make research in the whole database (which is mysql database) at once ?